# Display a common timer on every screen of the iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, timer

I have a requirement of displaying the same timer on every screen of the app once it gets started nomatter which part of the app the user navigates to. The attached screenshot is for reference. Please help.[image]

Comment: Please be more specific. Do you have to always show the whole header, or does the timer show in different fashion according to the viewcontroller it is being displayed in?

Comment: @il3v I think I was pretty clear "I have a requirement of displaying the same timer on every screen of the app". i.e nomatter on which viewcontroller of the app I go this timer should get dispayed and its one instance only.

Comment: Sorry, i misunderstood and thought you meant the indicator regarding the time since when the user is a member.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to attain this.

I’d suggest to create a “timer” class (inheriting from UIView) and a base viewcontroller that instantiates that subview. All your app’s VCs can then subclass from that base viewcontroller.

Comment: thats a very laborous job to add it manually on every screen, specially if u dont know how many screens might get added in future. I was hoping for a better approach which is less painfull.

Comment: if you instantiate it in the superclass, all the subclasses will inherit it

Comment: the problem is that its not visible at all times. So, when the condition becomes true in some viewcontroller it gets visble there and then it should get visible on all the screens with same state, i.e the timer instance should be same for every screen. Can you help further please.

Comment: What about a method that shows/hides the timer view when needed, again, defined in the superclass and called in its subclasses?